# Another “There was an error running the selected code generator:" with "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for" (SolutionName)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

On an MVC/EF project I tried adding an 'all-in' controller:
folder(rc) *Add > Controller > **MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework***

The process failed in an "*.. error running the selected code generator*", [not unknown to others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22There+was+an+error+running+the+selected+code+generator%3A%22)
( For this project we are bound to using NuGet Package versions not later than 3. ..)

A solution to my problem was:

- to delete all NuGet Packages or update them to the latest 3.1.11 (ms..efCore, ..Core.Design, ..Core.SqlServer, ..Core.Tools)
- uninstall the malefactor: **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design**(*)
- build the Solution
- ..and try the Add > Controller > "MVC Controller with views, using.." once more

Now, in the process of running this code-generation, Visual Studio itself selects the right version of **(*)**

That did it for us. ( Hopefully it saves someone some valuable time too )

Cheers

Comment: based on your description, it seems that you already have a working solution. Therefore, what is your current problem? Do you want to find a simple way to solve it?

Comment: Yes, I have. This is just my small contribution, for what it's worth. Maybe sharing the solution that worked for us could help other people out. As there are many answers offered in similar posts, none of the previous I found resolved our question. Thank you for your comment. I always appreciate the enlightening thoughts from the stackoverflow community. Just joined and wanted to give back for a change. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then the answer is that is a repeated error every time Microsoft issues an update for visual studio no mater if you update your vs or not the generator will stop functional until you do the two steps

1. update vs to latest
2. replace every package with the new latest compatible version

for me I have to update
from 3.1.13 to 3.1.16